# MongoDB API for Java : MongoInternalException on accessing a DBCursor

Tags: java, mongodb

After successfully connecting to the MongoDB database, I'm receiving this exception when trying to go through a DBCursor :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: couldn't get next element 
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:448)
```

Here is the code, the line with the while condition is the one raising the exception :

```
DBCollection upages = db.getCollection("upages");
DBCursor pageviewedbyuser = upages.find();
while (pageviewedbyuser.hasNext()) {
     etc etc
}
```

When accessing the `upages` collection from the Mongo shell, it seems clear that it's not empty. The `DBCursor` seems to be successfully loaded because there is this line in the error log :

```
SEVERE: MyPort.error called
java.io.IOException: finished reading objects but still have: 19553 bytes to read!'
```

Has anybody run into this error before? Any idea?

Comment: mongo version 1.7.3 and driver version 2.3